# Can't access my CKAN installation on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, ckan

I followed [installation guide](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/install-from-source.html) and [deployment guide](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/deployment.html) and I can access CKAN site but on port 5000, not on 8080.

What have I done wrong?

--edit1--
Error log.
`/var/log/apache2/ckan_default.error.log` is empty.
`/var/log/apache2/error.log` below:

```
[Wed Dec 16 03:56:05.341055 2015] [core:notice] [pid 31625] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Dec 16 05:25:00.457734 2015] [:error] [pid 32024] [client 188.68.224.62:59132] script '/var/www/html/wp/httptest.php' not found or unable to stat
[Wed Dec 16 06:46:59.218607 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 31625] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Wed Dec 16 06:46:59.367788 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 31625] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Dec 16 06:46:59.367809 2015] [core:notice] [pid 31625] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Dec 16 06:54:00.009154 2015] [:error] [pid 966] [client 188.68.224.62:40707] script '/var/www/html/wp/httptest.php' not found or unable to stat
[Wed Dec 16 13:07:30.925196 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 31625] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
```

--edit2--
Changed everything back to how the deployment guide says.
`/etc/apache2/sites-available/ckan_default.conf` below

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
    ServerName ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com
    ServerAlias www.ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com
    WSGIScriptAlias / /etc/ckan/default/apache.wsgi

    # Pass authorization info on (needed for rest api).
    WSGIPassAuthorization On

    # Deploy as a daemon (avoids conflicts between CKAN instances).
    WSGIDaemonProcess ckan_default display-name=ckan_default processes=2 threads=15

    WSGIProcessGroup ckan_default

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/ckan_default.error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/ckan_default.custom.log combined
    LogLevel info

    <IfModule mod_rpaf.c>
        RPAFenable On
        RPAFsethostname On
        RPAFproxy_ips 127.0.0.1
    </IfModule>

    <Directory />
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Also tried changing the 127.0.0.1:8080 to *:8080 and tried public IP address (Amazon Elastic IP) and DNS address. None of them work.

`ports.conf` has `listen 8080` (taken out listen 80)

wsgi script and nginx config as described in guide also.

I see the "Problem loading page" on Firefox visiting the root url on port 80 but visiting 8080 just hangs and both don't have HTTP response. I can still access CKAN on port 5000.

Comment: The deployment has not been successful. The docs say: In general, if it’s not working look in the log files in /var/log/apache2 for error messages. ckan_default.error.log should be particularly interesting.

Comment: Thanks for comment @DRead. CKAN error log is empty. Apache error log added in my question. Anything of interest there?

Comment: Is that wordpress there? Maybe you have another apache site configured which is grabbing all the requests. I think is an apache problem, not a ckan thing really.

Comment: @DRead yes, Wordpress is there too, but the ckan issue where it's not accessible at port 8080 but is at 5000 was same before I put Wordpress there. All that's changed for wordpress installation is adding listen 80 in apache ports.conf file - this made wordpress accessible at port 80, ckan at port 5000.

Comment: Maybe I should add that I am using Amazon EC2. Inbound rule is TCP port 80, 22, 5000, 8983, 443 accessible.

Comment: Can you paste your Apache configuration file for CKAN?

Comment: What HTTP status and headers are you getting?

Comment: @Nigel It's just as the guide. Please see the edit.

Comment: @DRead It's the "Problem loading page Unable to connect...." page, no response. When visiting :8080 it doesn't return any thing - might be redirecting in loop?

Comment: You're using a browser on your local machine? You said that Amazon doesn't allow connections to port 8080. Try it with curl from the box itself to confirm that this is the issue.

Comment: @DRead That, and permission of the wsgi script file seemed to have been the problem. Opened TCP 8080, and setting wsgi script file to 755 made it possible to connect on port 8080. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon EC2 doesn't allow connections to port 8080 by default, so could open the port if you really wanted to access it externally.

However accessing CKAN via 8080 is only for testing that the apache deployment is working, so it makes no sense to make it available externally - you can test apache is working by ssh-ing to the box and using curl.

The CKAN deployment instructions continue by telling you to install nginx as a reverse proxy, exposing CKAN on the normal port 80.

Comment: Opening port 8080 AND setting permission of wsgi script file to 755 made it possible to access ckan on port 8080, yes, but now that I think about it, the deployment guide was showing how to use nginx to cache and proxy, so that requests on port 80 for ckan is to be internally redirected to apache on port 8080. I am still unsuccessful in getting this to work.

Comment: I've improved the answer. I don't know about the permissions thing. It suggests EC2 needs this extra step compared to Ubuntu, but no doubt it would be helpful if you explained what the original permissions were and why.

Comment: My question does ask about connecting on 8080, although I was actually trying to deploy like the guide, so I guess this answers my question as it was written. I'll make another question if need be, regarding internal redirection. Thanks for help.